# Как можно упростить код?

Tags: ruby

Есть задача (условие перед кодом). В теории программа работает верно, однако есть пару нюансов в его работе. Заодно спрошу несколько вопросов, которые не менее волнуют меня

1. Как быть если у нас несколько человек имеет максимальную скорость печати?
2. Как в хеше упростить значение (берется случайное число максимально приближенное к реальному)
3. По вашему мнению оправдано ли использовать класс в данной ситуации? И как бы вы в целом изменили строение.
4. Почему не работает конструкция `result.better.med_speed.low_speed(list)`

PS, прошу не ругаться, если написанный код причинил вам боль.

#### Условие

Для некоторой группы учащихся (всего в группе 25 чел.) известны данные о скорости ввода текстовой информации с клавиатуры (количество введенных символов за 10 минут). Требуется составить отчет в следующем виде: напечатать фамилию и скорость ввода самого результативного учащегося; среднюю скорость ввода в данной группе;фамилии тех учащихся, скорость ввода которых ниже средней.

```
class Speed
  @med=0

  def better(list)
   #puts (list.sort_by{ |k,v| v}).to_s
   max=[]
   max << list.max_by { |k,v| v }
   puts max.to_s
   #puts list.to_a.to_s
  end

  def med_speed(list)
    @med=(list.values.inject(0){ |res,v| res+v})/25
    puts "#{@med} -- средняя скорость печати"
  end

  def low_speed(list)
    bad_stud = list.find_all{|k,v| v<@med}
    puts "#Скорость печати ниже среднего имеют: #{bad_stud.to_s}"
  end
end


list = {
  Tim:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Tereza:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Otto:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Pavel:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Kitti:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  George:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Sandra:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Patrik:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Nelson:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Fedel:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Hillary:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Marsel:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Boris:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Nikolay:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Juna:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Ivan:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Liza:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Karin:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Helga:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Josh:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Morris:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Wally:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Brigt:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Polina:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100)),
  Markiz:  (10 * (rand(150) + 100))
          }


#list.each{ |k,v| puts "#{k} : #{v}" }

result = Speed.new
result.better(list)
result.med_speed(list)
result.low_speed(list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Как быть если у нас несколько человек имеет максимальную скорость печати?

Лучше всего вернуть массив с пользователями, у которых максимальная скорость печати. Например, можно отсортировать ваш хэш по скорости печати, а потом отобрать первые элементы массива с одинаковой скоростью печати

```
arr = list.sort_by { |_k, v| -v }
arr.select { |e| arr.first[1] == e[1] }
```

> 2. Как в хеше упростить значение (берется случайное число максимально приближенное к реальному)

Для начала можно заменить выражение `(10 * (rand(150) + 100))` на более простое `rand(1500) + 1000` - оно короче и легче воспринимается. Далее у вас в хэше отличаются только имена - выражение для получения значения у всех одинаковое. Чтобы сократить размер кода, можно поступить следующим образом. Формируем массив имен, а затем преобразуем его в массив массивов вида `[[:Tim, 1558], ... [:Markiz, 2349]]`. Такой массив легко преобразуется в хэш при помощи метода `to_h`

```
list = %w(Tim Tereza Otto Pavel Kitti George Sandra Patrik Nelson Fedel Hillary
          Marsel Boris Nikolay Juna Ivan Liza Karin Helga Josh Morris Wally
          Brigt Polina Markiz)
list = list.map{ |e| [e.to_sym, rand(1500) + 1000]}.to_h
```

> 3. По вашему мнению оправдано ли использовать класс в данной ситуации?И как бы вы в целом изменили строение.

Использование класса возможно и оправдано, почему нет. Только класс у вас получился не совсем объектно-ориентированный, вы используете его в качестве контейнера методов.

Более того, у вас порядок вызова методов зависит друг от друга, пока переменная `@med` не сформирована, вы не можете пользоваться методом `low_speed`.

Кроме того, вы форматируете и выводите текст внутри методов. Это не правильно. Если захотите поменять текст, вам придется лезть внутрь класса, а это нарушает принцип инкапсуляции, да и просто не удобно.

Вы каждый раз передаете `list`, вместо того, чтобы один раз отдать его при инициализации объекта. Лучше будет, если вы заведете метод `initialize()`, которому передадите параметр `list`, а у всех остальных методов его уберете

```
def initialize(list)
  @list = list
end
```

С учетом всего выше-сказанного можно преобразовать ваш код следующим образом

```
class Speed
  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
  end

  def better
    arr = @list.sort_by { |_k, v| -v }
    arr.select { |e| arr.first[1] == e[1] }
  end

  def med_speed
    (@list.values.inject(0) { |res, v| res + v }) / 25
  end

  def low_speed
    med = med_speed
    @list.select { |_k, v| v < med }
  end
end

list = %w(Tim Tereza Otto Pavel Kitti George Sandra Patrik Nelson Fedel Hillary
          Marsel Boris Nikolay Juna Ivan Liza Karin Helga Josh Morris Wally
          Brigt Polina Markiz)
list = list.map{ |e| [e.to_sym, rand(1500) + 1000] }.to_h

result = Speed.new(list)
puts "Лучшие (скорость набора #{result.better.first.last})"
result.better.each do |e|
  puts e.first
end
puts "#{result.med_speed} -- средняя скорость печати"
puts 'Скорость печати ниже среднего имеют:'
result.low_speed.each do |e|
  puts "#{e.first} #{e.last}"
end
```

> 4. Почему не работает конструкция result.better.med_speed.low_speed(list)

Потому что в конце методов вы не возвращаете `self`, пока вы не возвращаете объект класса `Speed`, вызвать его методы не получится.

Comment: Спасибо, кое что почерпнул для себя и своей программы.

Однако я не понял момента
`arr = @list.sort_by { |_k, v| -v }`
почему перед ключом мы ставим нижнее подчеркивание?

И еще  один вопрос не совсем по теме, как можно вложить массив в массив. То есть: 
`m1 = []
m2 = [1,2,3]
m3 = [4,5,6]
...
и чтобы в результате было
m1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`
через << \ .push не получалось, к моему удивлению

Comment: @QWD666 Подчеркивание перед переменной или иногда просто подчеркиванием обозначают переменную, которая должна присутствовать по синтаксису, но фактически не используется. На самом деле это даже не я поставил, а rubocop, я просто прогнал скрипт по привычке, прежде чем сюда его запростить rubocop -a test.rb

Comment: @QWD666, странно, у меня с вложением массивов проблем не возникло 
m1 = []
m2 = [1,2,3]
m3 = [4,5,6]
m1 << m2
m1 << m3
p m1
Но вообще, конечно, лучше под новые вопросы, заводить новые темы - тут в комментариях не очень удобно писать и форматировать код.